# Show a Modal on react functional component using redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a dashboard page that shows a table list of all the posts, for each post I have and an edit button.

I'm trying to pop a modal when the edit button is clicked.
So I created a Modal component, which is rendered by the Dashboard component (this is a high order component equal to the App compo)
and I added a modal slice with redux toolkit and I successfully managed to change the modal state when the edit button is clicked but the modal doesn't show up.
I hope that I was thorough enough with what I'm trying to achieve, I also hope that you will help me guys, and now I'll share with you some of the code.

EditPostModal.jsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal'
import editPostSlice, {
  getPostToEditModal,
} from '../../store/slices/editPost'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({.....}))

export default function SimpleModal() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const modal = useSelector(getPostToEditModal)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  console.log('HEYYYY', modal) // modal is undefined

  const handleClose = () => {
    dispatch(editPostSlice.actions.closeModal())
  }

  if (!modal) return null

  return (
    <Modal
      className={classes.modal}
      open
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
      aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
    >
      <h1>I AM THE MODAL</h1>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to debug is to check if the modal will open without redux toolkit slice.

Also, can you confirm that the `modal` variable always return something other than a falsy value?

Comment: I fixed it, it turns out that the issue was in editPostSlice, I wasn't fetching the modal state correctly.